# How to pass text of clicked object to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, hyperlink, click

So what I want is to get the text fro of a clicked  and passed it to a variable, then echoing this variable into another a.

This is as far as I have gotten, though this obviously doesn't work. How should I do this?

```
var aOneText = $(clickedA).text();
$('a.one').click(function(){
        var clickedA = $(this);
    $('a.two').text(aOneText);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not assigning `text` to `aOneText` in the event.

```
var aOneText;
$('a.one').click(function(){    
    var clickedA = $(this);
    aOneText = clickedA.text();
    $('a.two').text(aOneText);
});
```

Comment: thanks a million!
And thanks to everyone else who gave quick answers!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('a.one').click(function(){
    var clickedA = $(this).text();
     $('a.two').text(clickedA);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.text()` that will get the text inside of DOM and return it.

```
$('a.one').click(function(){
    var clickedA = $(this);
     $('a.two').text(clickedA.text());
});
```

as per your code you need to modify it as below

```
var aOneText;
$('a.one').click(function(){
        var clickedA = $(this);
    aOneText = clickedA.text();
    $('a.two').text(aOneText);
});
```

you were defining `var aOneText = $(clickedA).text();` out side click event code so it will not have any value instead jQuery give you error because `$(clickedA)` may not exists if you did not declared it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.one').click(function(){
    $('a.two').text($(this).text());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('a.one').click(function(){
    $('a.two').text( $(this).text());
});
```